# Error: Failed to open port. Permission denied

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have been installing Hokuyo UTM-30LX drivers on ROS following
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers
roslaunch hokuyo_node hokuyo_test.launch

as suggested by http://answers.ros.org/question/35022/hokuyo-laser-installation-ubuntu/,

But I came across with the problem Error: Failed to open port. Permission denied.So I found that there is a solution in hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting 1.2 (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting)
But there is no specific and clear solution for this problem.
I don't know how to do it next!!!

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41540/error:-failed-to-open-port.-permission-denied./) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on 2012-08-15**:
In the block that start with SUBSYSTEMS, put that in a file called 99-hokuyo.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ There should be similar .rules files there for comparison.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-15**:
That's actually already an answer, you should post it as such.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-15**:
Try chmod first, if that works setup udev as @dougbot01 said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @dougbot01 and @dornhege:

Try using chmod and then in the block that start with SUBSYSTEMS, put that in a file called 99-hokuyo.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ There should be similar .rules files there for comparison.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0